# Select x number of records in reverse order that are lesser than a date

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table where date is one of the column.  Assume the date is ordered by ascending order.

I am trying to fetch 7 records in ascending order that are older than a particular given date in reverse order.

**Example**

```
======================
ID           Date
=======================
1           2016-09-01
2           2016-09-03
3           2016-09-07
4           2016-09-09
5           2016-09-13
6           2016-09-15
7           2016-09-19
8           2016-09-22
9           2016-09-23
```

Assume I want to select 3 records in ascending order that are lesser than 2016-09-15 in reverse order.

The output I would need is

```
************************
ID           Date
=======================
3           2016-09-07
4           2016-09-09
5           2016-09-13
```

How can I achieve this in MySQL?

Comment: An example might be helpful to clarify what you're wanting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it should be just this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM Example
  WHERE
    my_date<'2016-09-15'
  ORDER BY
    my_date DESC
  LIMIT 3
) s
ORDER BY my_date ASC
```

Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d037/1).

Comment: If I put DESC in my example it displays in the order 13, 09, 07. But I want the list as 07, 09, 13.  If I put ASC in my example it display 01, 03, 07 which is entirely wrong.

Comment: @Malaiselvan oh okay, now I got it. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: thanks.  It works.  However since I use PHP I get the output of first query and then put a array_reverse to reverse the array.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select  * FROM table where date_field < 'some_date' order by date_field desc LIMIT 7
```

Comment: Umm, there is no `TOP` operator present in `MySQL`.

Comment: Whoops was thinking of MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY and LIMIT when used together could get a little tricky.

If you need records older than a date and and sorted latest first
Query suggested by @fthiella should work.

Same applies when you need records later than a date and sorted earliest first. You just have to order by date.

If you need records older than a date sorted oldest first, you cannot order by and limit in a single query.

You might have to do something like

```
select my_date from 
(
select my_date from 
    my_table where my_date < '08/24/2014' 
    order by my_date desc
    limit 7
 ) a 
 order by my_date
```

Outer order by desc or not based on the order you want.